# Git: multiple branches deployment workflow

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to understand how to best improve my workflow when working with multiple branches each of which will deploy to a specific environment.

Let's start by saying I'm using BitBucket to host my git repository and I have three branches on it: `origin/master`, `origin/staging` and `origin/production`.

Whenever I complete a new task I commit the task to my local branch `master` and then I push it to `origin/master`. After that if I want to deploy that commit to staging I simply open the branches and run a "sync" (using the BitBucket feature) so that the branch `origin/staging` matches with `origin/master`.

However, when I look at the repository on SourceTree it feels like I made a mess and that this is probably not the correct way of doing it.

This is how the repository looks like on SourceTree:

[image]

And this is how it looks on BitBucket:

[image]
[image]

First of all: Why does it say that `origin/production` and `origin/staging` are respectively 4 and 6 commits ahead of `origin/master`?

Secondly, if what I'm doing is wrong/can be improved, what would you suggest me to do?

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your workflow. The SourceTree graph looks more convoluted than necessary, but if you trace all the lines carefully you will see that it is identical to the graph shown by BitBucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`production` and `staging` are ahead of your `master` branch because there are merge commits that are not present in `master`. You can easily see this in your SourceTree screenshot: `origin/production` is four (merge) commits ahead of master, the four commits with the `Merged master into production` message. It's similar with your `staging` branch.

You get into this situation because you repeatedly merge your `master` branch into the other branches, but never merge the other branches back into master. This is not wrong. As long as the "Ahead" count does not bother you, you're all set. If you prefer to have no commits ahead of `master`, you can just merge `production` and `staging` back into master. This will not change anything of your data, the merge commits will just become part of your `master`s' history as well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it helped me :)